Split resources for tvos and ios in SPM manifest file
Can't find any information on how to do package swift file with a single library which will support iOS and tvOS apps. But different xib and some source files, but shared networking classes.
How its possible? Or it isn't?
Maybe I should use different sub-targets for each platform and import it by precompile macros in code?
